# How to return empty array from Mongo DB aggregation with $push?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to get an [] when running Mongo DB aggregation with $group and $push. I have tried:

```
$group: {
 _id: { _id: '$_id', name: '$name'},
 occupied: {
  $push: null
 }
}
```

and

```
$group: {
 _id: { _id: '$_id', name: '$name'},
 occupied: {
  $push: undefined
 }
}
```

As expected the result is:

```
occupied: [null]
```

Anyone knows if I can get ***occupied: []*** anyhow? (Node.js)

Comment: Are the contents of `occupied` irrelevant with respect to the actual data getting grouped? Said another way, you want an empty array for all groups? If so then I'd suggest appending that field in a subsequent $addFields stage instead. (Also if the `_id` field coming in to this `$group` is unmodified from the source documents then it is already unique and you should not be using `$group` at all)

Comment: Maybe it sounds stupid, but you can add a `$addFields` stage after `$group` and set the `occupied` to `[]`. i.e: `$addFields: {"occupied": []}`. This will overwrite your previous `occupied` field, but I suppose this doesn't matter.

Comment: Please edit your question to show 2 or 3 input docs and what your target result is that involves `[]`.   If there is a `_id`/`name` pair used by `$group`, then *something* must be `$pushed` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to get an [] is to $push a non existing document field, something like:

```
occupied: { $push: '$placeholder'}
```

With placeholder field not existing in the collection, of course